# Loki, libmtp error when copying to Android device

Tags: release-loki, android, mtp

1-st time here. The PC sees my phone and mounts it. [image]I can copy to the internal memory of the phone, but I can't copy to the sdcard of the phone. It shows me the error of the picture I provided.
Distro: Loki, latest updates.

Answer (score 1):

This might only be a file system limitation on your android device / sdcard. Double-check its file system and the characters that it supports.

You might want to test to copy files without any special characters (such as `: ; , '` etc.)